# Need to Link Parent and Child Objects at creation with Lookup Fields

Tags: trigger

We use a survey solution that creates a Contact Record and a Custom Object Record, "Profile" at the same time. I have a "Contact" lookup field in the profile object. I need a way to automatically link the records via the lookup field at creation.
Right now there is a "Response ID" that deposits the survey's unique identifier in both the Contact and Profile. I am currently using this field to update the records via Dataloader. Pretty simple process but the Market Research team really needs to see the connection when the records are created. My hypothesis is that the same "'Update Contact', Lookup via 'ResponseID'" process could work using a trigger or Process Builder field update, but have yet to make that work.
Any ideas?

Comment: As long as one is inserted first, then it's easy to query it for the externalId field that links them when the 2nd one is inserted and populate SF id based url fields that links the two using after insert trigger.